# Link several URLS from one table to a single record in another table?

Tags: php, mysql

Okay I have two mysql tables, one which hold details on films ie title description etc. I have a column in this table named awards, now I need to be able to attach or link several images to a single record within this column.

I have a separate table which holds links to the urls of the png's of the Awards, but I'm unsure how to link them.

Now part two is to then display this information on a page with each url separate and in its own div, I'm guessing that explode() could work to split.

I know that it is a One to Many Relationship but I couldn't find anything that would do the job.

If anyone could shed some light on this I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2):

One technique you can do is JOIN the two tables and use SELECT GROUP_CONCAT to concat the values as a single variable and yes, you can you explode() to break them out later.

Indeed use GROUP_CONCAT and this is what you can do:

```
mysql> SELECT f.name, GROUP_CONCAT(a.url SEPARATOR ",") AS awards FROM film f JOIN awards a ON a.film_id = f.id;
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| name                  | awards                                                                      |
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| River Runs Through It | http://www.ariverrunsthroughit.com,http://www.webby.com,http://www.imdb.com |
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

---

In PHP, you query the database using query above, and say it was output in a variable called $row then you could explode the awards variable and output into separate DIVS as you noted.

```
<?php
// connection

$query = mysql_query("SELECT f.name, GROUP_CONCAT(a.url SEPARATOR ",") AS awards FROM film f JOIN awards a ON a.film_id = f.id");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   $title = $row['name'];
   // get awards
   $awards = explode(",", $row['awards']);

   // output title and awards (iterate through array)
   echo "<hr>";
   echo "<div id='title'>$title</div>";
   foreach ($awards AS $award) {
      echo "<div id='award'>$award</div>";
   }
}
```

---

Here is SQL to build the test:

```
mysql> create table film (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(24), PRIMARY KEY (id));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO film VALUES (1, "River Runs Through It");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE awards (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, film_id INT NOT NULL, url VARCHAR(64), title VARCHAR(24), PRIMARY KEY (id));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO awards VALUES (1,1,'http://www.ariverrunsthroughit.com','Our Award'), (2,1,'http://www.webby.com', 'Webby Award'), (3,1,'http://www.imdb.com', 'IMDB Award');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a join.  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

So in MYSQL it would be this:

```
SELECT * FROM `movies` WHERE `movie_id` = 1 JOIN `awards` ON `awards.mid` = `movies.movie_id`
```

Hope this helps :)  If the names overlap then you may need to alias the tables/columns: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have all the images in a single field in the result you can use

```
SELECT
films.*
GROUP_CONCAT(images.url SEPARATOR ',') as image_urls
FROM films
LEFT JOIN images ON images.film_id = film.id
WHERE ...
```

and then use explode(',',$row->image_urls) to separate the urls.